# Are there any distributed transactional filesystem implementations that I can actually use?

Tags: filesystems, distributed-filesystems, transactional-replication

I've been searching for distributed transactional filesystems so I don't have to make my own subpar implementation.

I've only come across two:

- [Warp Transactional Filesystem](https://www.usenix.org/conference/nsdi16/technical-sessions/presentation/escriva) - The website is no longer up, and the source code is not production-ready unless I get a license for the production code
- [Wave Transactional Filesystem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.07821v1.pdf) - I cannot find any source code for this

Are there any popular open source distributed transactional filesystems? I would have expected at least one to be in existence somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no idea what to expect from a transactional file-system I turned to Wikipedia and immediately found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS - which although possibly still supported also sounds like another [evolutionary dead-end](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/deprecation-of-txf).

The general consensus seems to be that specific requirements will need to be addressed by the application logic and/or by using a database (which are generally designed for managing transactions really well) and won't be magically solved by a file-system, not even by feature rich [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS).